# Is there a way to trigger "find" in a browser through javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, find, words

[image]

Does javascript allow for to trigger a "find" action with a keyword on the current page?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no cross-browser way to do this. (I don't even know of *one* browser that exposes that functionality.)